# Changing desktop background depending on the time of day via script Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, script, vbscript, desktop-customization

Hello it is my first time using this website so I hope I am not asking the question in wrong format.

Anyways, as the title says I have a similar problem [to a thread that was answered a while ago](https://superuser.com/questions/436978/changing-wallpaper-depending-on-time-of-day-via-script-or-batch-file?answertab=votes#tab-top) that had the answer but would not work for my computer that is running windows 8.1 when I tried to run it to test it out. I am sure I followed the instructions by changing the path to where the image is located and I was wondering what would I have to change to make it work or if the code is perfectly fine and I probably just mess up somewhere.

```
dim shell
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wallpaper = "C:\path\to\wallpaper.jpg"
shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", wallpaper
shell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True
```

I have also tried the [original code](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7586006_script-change-desktop-background.html) but I end up getting an error saying the system cannot find the file specified on the last line of code.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This line dont have any effect on my Windows 7: shell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True. So script dont work and of course dont update background. [This powershell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440135/powershell-script-from-shortcut-to-change-desktop) should works, but i cant and dont want test it since powershell disabled. [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts) link how activate it. And you can run it with cmd **powershell "C:\powershell.ps1"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad answer and should not be used:

This script emulate right click on picture and press "Set as desktop background". Script usage should be clear `SetWallPaper "directory to picture", "filename of picture", "name context menu to run"`.

```
'File encoding should be in ANSI
SetWallPaper "C:\icons\", "Potato-icon.png", "Set as desktop &background"

Sub SetWallPaper(WallPaperFolder, WallpaperFile,VerbName)
dim objShell, objFolder, objFolderItem, objVerb, colVerbs
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
set objFolder=objShell.NameSpace(WallPaperFolder)
set objFolderItem=objFolder.ParseName(WallPaperFile)
set colVerbs=objFolderItem.Verbs
for each objVerb in colVerbs
    'msgbox objVerb ,0, "Press CTRL+C for copy text" 'uncomment for debug names in contextmenu
    if objVerb=VerbName then
        'x=msgbox(objVerb ,0, "omg found")
        objVerb.DoIt
        'Without the sleep command the change never takes effect on Win7.
        wscript.sleep(2000)
        wscript.quit
    end if
next
End Sub
```

If your Windows have different name for "set as desktop background" when right click on picture:

- You should uncomment line(remove single quote) after **for each objVerb in colVerbs**
- Then run script and find(ENTER for next
  message) equal string "Set as desktop &background"
  for your language then press CTRL+C for save message.
- Open notepad and press CTRL+V so message will be pasted. Copy this
  name to script.

based on [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/it-IT/833eede7-ec49-4a09-b3ab-f2a8a0fde947/set-as-desktop-background-from-vbs)

If you dont make mistake will works atleast in Windows 7.